# Produce .lib of header-only library that depends on external resources

Tags: cmake, subdirectory

**EDIT:** I've read up and understood the initial issue was caused by scanning-header-only not having cpp files and thus a lib file not being generated. Edited the question to reflect that extra understanding:

My current project folder structure and relevant CMakeLists content:

```
leveling
├── CMakeLists.txt: add_subdirectory(deps) 
└── deps
    ├── CMakeLists.txt: add_subdirectory(scanning-header-only)
    └── scanning
        ├── CMakeLists.txt: add_subdirectory(deps)
        │                   add_library(scanning-header-only file.h)
        │                   target_include_directories(scanning-header-only PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/deps/tinyxml2)
        │                   target_link_libraries(scanning-header-only PUBLIC tinyxml2)
        └── deps
            ├── CMakeLists.txt: add_subdirectory(tinyxml2)
            └── tinyxml2
```

But a scanning-header-only library file is not being generated, and thus the root project can't target_link_libraries(leveling scanning-header-only) and has had to `target_include_directories(leveling  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/deps/scanning-header-only/deps/tinyxml2`)

***Is it possible to target_link_library a header-only library that depends on external resources?***

I see that a header-only library without external resource dependency could be `add_library(.. INTERFACE)`, but I'm failing to do so with the dependency on tinyxml2

A dirty workaround is adding and empty cpp file to scanning-header-only so a lib file is generated, but is there a correct way to do this?

---

---

Here is minimal example v1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1lbajz3xoat1bg/leveling-header-only-test%20v1.zip?dl=0

leveling CMakeLists.txt:
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

```
set(LEVELING_NAME leveling)

project(${LEVELING_NAME})

#
# To put tinyxml.dll next to the executable, to workaround having to make tinyxml2.dll reachable in PATH
#
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

math(EXPR platform_bits "${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} * 8")
set(platform_dir bin/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}-${platform_bits})

foreach(config DEBUG RELEASE RELWITHDEBINFO MINSIZEREL)
    foreach(var
            CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${config}
            CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${config}
            CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${config}
            )
        set(${var} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${platform_dir}/${config}")
        string(TOLOWER "${${var}}" ${var})
    endforeach()
endforeach()
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#

add_subdirectory(deps)

add_executable(${LEVELING_NAME} main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${LEVELING_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/deps/scanning 
)

target_link_libraries(${LEVELING_NAME} 
    xml-reading
)

set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT ${LEVELING_NAME}) # Set Startup Project in VS. Implemented in CMake v3.6
set_target_properties(${LEVELING_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}") # Set Working Directory of project in VS. Implemented in CMake v3.8
```

scanning CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(XML_NAME xml-reading)

project(${XML_NAME})

#
# To put tinyxml.dll next to the executable, to workaround having to make tinyxml2.dll reachable in PATH
#
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

math(EXPR platform_bits "${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} * 8")
set(platform_dir bin/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}-${platform_bits})

foreach(config DEBUG RELEASE RELWITHDEBINFO MINSIZEREL)
    foreach(var
            CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${config}
            CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${config}
            CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${config}
            )
        set(${var} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${platform_dir}/${config}")
        string(TOLOWER "${${var}}" ${var})
    endforeach()
endforeach()
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#

add_subdirectory(deps)

add_library(${XML_NAME} INTERFACE CamerasXML.h)
target_include_directories(${XML_NAME} INTERFACE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/deps/tinyxml2
)
target_link_libraries(${XML_NAME} 
    INTERFACE tinyxml2
)
```

which yields

```
CMake Error at deps/scanning/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_library): 
  add_library INTERFACE library requires no source arguments.
```

Comment: The PUBLIC keyword to target_include_directories is supposed to take care of this.  Any target that links against "scanning" should automatically add that include directory as well.  Boil your example down to the minimum CMakeLists.txt and post it...

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to add the extra target_include_directories for the `scanning` target if the `tinyxml2` library  used `target_include_directories( tinyxml2 PUBLIC .)` to include it's header files as part of the target definition.  Then it should populate the includes path of everything that uses that it like `target_link_libraries(scanning tinyxml2)`.

Comment: Also `include_directories` doesn't work that way.  You would have to have one `include_directories` at the top level for all include folder locations.

Comment: Hi, txs for pointing that out. Due to that I've understood a bit more of the issue and edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `add_library(${XML_NAME} INTERFACE)` (not specifying any source files), while having `target_include_directories(${XML_NAME} INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/deps/tinyxml2)` and `target_link_libraries(${XML_NAME} INTERFACE tinyxml2)` will do the trick.

The tinyxml2 includes are made available to the parent project, and the tinyxml2 library is linked in the parent project.

Answer (score 1):

A `.lib` is when you create a STATIC (`.lib`) or SHARED (`.lib` and `.dll`) library on Windows. What you want is an INTERFACE library and it generates no files.  http://mariobadr.com/creating-a-header-only-library-with-cmake.html has an example.  Then you can use the following commands listed here, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries, to populate the interface.  Notice that it uses INTERFACE not PUBLIC.

```
target_link_libraries(INTERFACE),
target_link_options(INTERFACE),
target_include_directories(INTERFACE),
target_compile_options(INTERFACE),
target_compile_definitions(INTERFACE), and
target_sources(INTERFACE),
```

I've never actually used this but I assume it works as documented.

Comment: Thxs for the effort, but we're not there yet.
add_library(scanning-header-only INTERFACE file.h)
target_link_libraries(scanning-header-only INTERFACE tinyxml2) complains that tinyxml2 is not an interface something somthing :/

Comment: huh, after creating the minimal example, just that did the trick :/ :), txs and sorry